# Java List not contains object

Tags: java, list

I have a class Person with properties id, firstname, lastname

```
List<Person> allPersons; // list of existant persons from database
List<Person> persons; // list of persons for treatement
```

What's the best way to do this :
if allPersons is empty or the couple (person.getFirstname, person.getLastname) not in allPersons then create(person)

I try something like this :

```
List<Person> personsToCreate = new ArrayList<>();

if (allPersons.isEmpty()) {
    personsToCreate = persons;
}

for (Person person : allPersons) {
    for (Person personToTreat : persons) {
        if (!(person.getFirstName().equals(personToTreat.getFirstName()) && person.getLastName().equals(personToTreat.getLastName()))) {
            personsToCreate.add(personToTreat);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far to get the desired behaviour?

Comment: Why don't you consider using the composite key of firstName and lastName as unique in the DB. This will ensure for that there are no duplicates in the DB and will not lose efficiency by checking if the person exist in db for every single insertion.

Comment: Unless this is homework, people have duplicate names, there are many `ryan leach` in this world.

Comment: This Person class is just a simplification of what I really want to do.
In reality, the class is a lot more complex, I just wanted to ask for advice on how to do it well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt won't work since you're handling the creation in the loop, so you will end up adding several persons there.

Just write it the way you described it:

```
if (allPersons.isEmpty() || !allPersons.contains(person))
  allPersons.add(person)
```

Now, in order for this to work you have to ask yourself an important question: What exactly constitutes "the same person"?

You described it as same first name/last name, so make sure your `equals` and `hashcode` methods are implemented as such. Probably that's a simplificiation, but the rules still apply.  When describing an entity, always thing about what uniquely identifies that entity, and use that for implementing `equals` and `hashcode`.

Secondly,  since `allPersons` can't possibly contain the same person twice, it is a `Set`, not a `List`.  In that case you can even ditch the check, because the set will automatically make sure only one copy is present.

Third, the check for emptyness is superfluous.  Obviously if it's empty, contains will always be false.